# Python Matplotlib required x_ticks don't appear on a radar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts, radar-chart

Ok, I'm plotting a radar chart with following wind direction data:

```
direction = ['N', 'NW', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'NW', 'NW', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'N', 'NW', 'NW', 'NW', 'N', 'SE', 'NE', 'E', 'E', 'NW', 'NE', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'W', 'NW', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'NW', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'NW', 'W', 'N', 'SE', 'E', 'NE', 'E', 'NE']
```

I collect list of attributes for ticks on the chart:

```
attributes = ['E', 'NE', 'N', 'NW', 'W', 'SW', 'S', 'SE']
```

Then I make list of values corresponding to each direction in attributes and angles of the axes to plot the data :

```
values = [6, 4, 8, 10, 16, 0, 1, 2, 6]
angles = [n / float(len(attributes)) * 2 * math.pi for n in range(len(attributes)[![enter image description here][1]][1])]
angles += angles [:1]
```

Then make a plot:

```
ax3 = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
plt.xticks(angles[:-1], attributes)
ax3.plot(angles,values)
ax3.fill(angles, values, 'teal', alpha=0.1)
ax3.set_title("Direction")
plt.show()
```

And it works just fine (see **pic_1**). BUT when I use the same thing in my project, **the ticks don't appear on the chart (see pic_2**)! Here's the code (I have 4 sublots on the Figure, the radar chart is ax3 - bottom right one):

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (1, 0))
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (1, 1), polar=True)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 1))
[...ax1...]
[...ax2...]
[...ax4...]
ax3.set_xticks(angles[:-1], attributes)
ax3.plot(angles, values)
ax3.fill(angles, values, 'teal', alpha=0.1)
ax3.set_title('Направление ветра')
plt.show()
```

What's wrong with it?

[image: pic_1 **with ticks**]

[image: pic_2 **no ticks**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding the ticks and tick labels to your axes (instead of using `pyplot.xticks`, as in your first snippet) you need to assign the tick locations and labels separately. Try the following, instead of `ax3.set_xticks(angles, attributes)` do:

```
ax3.set_xticks(angles)
ax3.set_xticklabels(attributes)
```

Comment: Indeed, `.set_xticks(angles, attributes)` is not valid use of the API. It would be interpreted as `.set_xticks(angles, minor=attributes)`, meaning you want to set the minor ticks.

Comment: @ Francisca Concha-Ramírez Thank you very much, it works just as supposed to! But I don't quite understand methods in my first test snippet and in my actual project (yeah, I know, I didn't have time to study matplotlib properly) - why in one case I should use '.xticks()', and in another case - '.set_xticks()'. It is quite unclear. 
And what is the difference between 'xticks' and 'xticklabels' (isn't the label the legend?)

Comment: @ Francisca Concha-Ramírez And is there a way to shift title a bit? Because the title and the "N" wind direction overlap a bit.

Comment: @Outlaw I'm glad it worked for you :) Could you please mark the answer as accepted? Regarding your question: `set_xticks` only sets the locations of the ticks (in this case the angles), but the labels themselves for each tick have to be set separately. The reason `pyplot.xticks` works by itself in your first snippet is because you only had one subplot, so you didn't need to assign ticks and labels to each axes separately (no idea why the syntaxes are different, though). For your overlapping text problem, try: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html

Comment: @ Francisca Concha-Ramírez It's strange, cause I point out that it is **ax3**.set_xticks(...
Anyway, thank you very much! As far as I got it, ticks only set kind of 'marks' on the circle (that are invisible in my case), just like we put marks on the usual xy-plot on both axes. And to show labels of these marks we have to 'set_xticklabels'.

Comment: @ Francisca Concha-Ramírez Maybe you know (don't want to bother people with another topic), how in my case can I add small (red or any) dots to the radar chart at the line, where it reaches it's maximum value on each axis? I mean putting a dot to each node (point, knot, apex) of a graph? (sorry for stating it a bit confusing, sometimes it's hard for me to convey the idea in foreign language)

Comment: @Outlaw I think it's better if you ask a new question for that, that way more people can find it and both be able to help you and make use of the answers. Also I don't have much space in the comments to answer.